# Working with entities in viewmodel with knockout.js

Tags: jquery, knockout.js

I'm learning knockout.js. I have a basic web page that allows a user to add and edit an entity. In an attempt to avoid duplication, I wanted to define an instance of the entity within the view model, like one can do in Silverlight.

```
<input id="orderQuantity" type="text" data-bind="value:order.quantity" />
<input id="orderPrice" type="text" data-bind="value:order.price" />
<select id="orderType" data-bind="options:orderTypes">

var viewModel = {
  order: ko.observable(null),
  orderTypes: ko.observableArray(['Priority', 'Express', 'Normal' ]),

  init: function(o) {
    // Determine if we're working with an existing order, or a new one.
    if (o == null) {
      this.order(null);
    }
    else {
      this.order(new order(o));
    }
  }
};

$().ready(function () {
    ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
});

// The following is defined in a seperate .js file. 
// I've verified its getting called by using an 'alert'
var order = function(o) {
  this.id = o.id;
  this.quantity = o.quantity;
  this.price = o.price;
  this.orderType = o.orderType;
}
```

My problem is when I call init, I've noticed that the order gets created. However, the values associated with the order are not bound in the form elements. How do I make this form work? i would like to daisy-chain so that I can keep my class definitions seperate so that I can re-use them.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is the best solution for you, but I have it working at http://jsfiddle.net/photo_tom/vcu67/1/.

there were two issues -

1. By making order a ko.observable, then your references need to be order().quantity, no order.quantity like you have.  When you make order an observable, you have to reference it as a function.
2. I would change your data model like I have in the fiddle.  In your example, because each object in your Order model is not composed of observable, no updates from the screen will be reflected in the data model.

Hope this meets your needs